# Get tasks done every Monday for the next 5 weeks

Tags: c#

How do I get built-up start hours and end hours that if a user just wants to have done several tasks eg every Monday from 08 to 11 the next x number of weeks.

So how can I just do it in a smart way.

I have MoreAdd which tells how many weeks ahead it should make that way.

When I just create a single task. Then it looks like this.

```
var sTimer = model.StartTime;
var eTimer = model.EndTime;

SignUpInfo addSignUpInfo = new SignUpInfo
                    {
                        CompanyId = companyId,
                        Title = model.Title,
                        Info = model.Info,
                        StartTime = sTimer,
                        EndTimer = eTimer,
                        Closed = false,
                        Pay = PayValue,
                        TaskDone = false,
                        CreateTime = DateTime.Now,
                        CategoriId = model.SelectedKategori
                    };

                    _db.SignUpInfo.Add(addSignUpInfo);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
```

But how will I only do that if I write 5 then make it one from the next Monday and 5 times forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *guess* you are struggling with determining the start- and end `DateTimes` for the next 5 weeks from the next Monday. You could use this method:

```
static IEnumerable<(DateTime start, DateTime end)> GetTimes(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, DayOfWeek startDay, int countWeeks)
{
    if(endTime < startTime) throw new ArgumentException("TODO");
    TimeSpan diff = endTime - startTime;
    int daysUntilWeekDay = ((int) startDay - (int) startTime.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
    DateTime beginningDate = startTime.AddDays(daysUntilWeekDay);
    for (int i = 0; i <= countWeeks; i++)
    {
        DateTime date = beginningDate.AddDays(7 * i);
        yield return (start: date, end:date.Add(diff));
    }
}
```

---

Example:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2019, 01, 20, 8, 0, 0); //yesterday, sunday, 8 o clock in the morning
foreach(var x in GetTimes(dt, dt.AddHours(3), DayOfWeek.Monday, 5))
    Console.WriteLine("Start:{0} End:{1}", x.start, x.end);
```

With this method it's easy to build a loop that uses your existing code to save the tasks.

Comment: Thanks for help!. i have fix `int i = 0` to `int i = 1`

Comment: @J.Petersen: i wanted to include the next monday and the following 5, thats why i have used `<=` and not `<`

Comment: Okay :) i can see what u mean.